# What is wrong with my Heroku & Godaddy SSL Configuration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, dns, hosting

I generated a private key with hombrew, and used it when generating an SSL cert from Godaddy. I then ran concat on the two certs Godaddy gave to me into one cert.  I used the original private key and generated cert and created a Heroku SSL endpoint. It gave me a url like example1212.herokussl.com as the target for a CNAME on Godaddy.  I did added that record and now my page cannot be found.

Anyone know what could be going on?  I cant figure it out.  Here were the guides I used:
http://www.joshwright.com/tips/setup-a-godaddy-ssl-certificate-on-heroku
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was when generating the CSR, I did not know that the 'Common Name' that must be the domain name.  I thought it was like company name or developer name or something. Everything was fine after I re-created the CSR. Hope this helps someone